# How to hide PHP code on the server from other person under root?

Tags: linux

Good day!

There are PHP scripts, classes, configs. All this stuff is interconnected, I need to give a person access to the server so that he works (started under the root) with these scripts, while changing only the config files, and in order to not be able to view the source code.

I've researched various free obsfukators which converting code into something:

```
<?php include(base64_decode('Li4vY29uZmlnLnBocA=='));include(base64_decode('cHJpdmF0ZS92ZW5kb3IvYXV0b2xvYWQucGhw'));$krc_5bf7f45b=[];foreach($bhi_6f9322e1as $xol_e8b7be43){$xol_e8b7be43=explode(base64_decode('Og=='),$xol_e8b7be43);try{$uic_c59361f8=new \xee_d9cb1642\cko_659fc60();$uic_c59361f8->ldc_aa08cb10($xol_e8b7be43[0],$xol_e8b7be43[1]);$krc_5bf7f45b[]=$uic_c59361f8;}catch(Exception $wky_efda7a5a)
```

1. What if the files of configs have variable names and it turns out that when obfuscating the main working code, the variables have different names? Not to force the user to run through the obsfukation corrected config every time? So far, this option seems the only one.
2. Is it possible inside the server under Ubuntu to somehow limit the ability to copy or view or download certain files or make some other methods of protection-hiding, but at the same time with the ability to run this code. It was thought to hide the code somewhere in the depths of the file system folders, calling them random names, and run them somehow through the symlinks by the file name or something like that. Is it possible to?
3. Option not to provide root access to the server, but to launch via the browser, to give access only to FTP to upload the config to a separate folder. But there are a number of points - all scripts run up to a week, and must be executed as root. How to solve it?

Comment: If you give somebody root access, they can read all the files, and decode all the things. Additionally, if they can *run* a file, they *must* be able to read it.

Comment: Give them sudo access to only run the specific command they need. Don't give them unrestricted root access just because they need to run one command as root